# Voltage level when connectiong two power sources

Tags: voltage, battery-charging, voltage-measurement

I've experienced the following situation the other day.
When connected to this smart powers charger (never seen one of those), the battery voltage dropped.

Made me wonder about two questions.

**1.**

[image]

What kind of voltage should the `Battery Charger` had to have to lower the voltage? -0.6?

**2.**

[image]

When connecting two different power supplies with different voltage levels in parallel to one another is it predictable what the voltage levels will be? Where would I have to measure to get the exact values of voltages `U1` or `U2` in this scenario? The connection wire should not be considered ideal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from wiring non idealities, what you are missing is **output resistance**.

Each non-ideal voltage (current) source has a series (parallel) output resistor, which is ideally zero (infinite).

When you parallel two power sources the voltage you measure across them depends on each output resistance, even neglecting wire resistance.

As an example, have a look at this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsRTvp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's suppose you measure voltage where the arrows are, plus terminal on top, minus on bottom.

Total voltage across resistors is 1V, current is then 6.6mA, the voltage you measure is about 1.67V.

As you can see the voltage depends on the sources voltage **and** their output resistance. If your wires are non ideal you will experience a voltage drop because of this 'fight current' that is flowing because the sources fight to 
set their voltage.

But what if you connect two *ideal* voltage sources in parallel? Well, you can't, and our way of modelling electronic circuits does not care about describing the impossible.

There is actually a catch: some devices can not be modeled as voltage/current sources, as your smart charger. First of all, most voltage (current) sources have a maximum output current (voltage). Up to the maximum the output is guaranteed to be stable, after that it drops. Moreover, some devices vary their output and can even switch between voltage source and current source mode.

I am sure you now understand that such a connection, which is usually undesirable, must be analyzed carefully, and the outcome might be very different depending on the nature of the devices.

Answer (score 0):

**#1 - Are you absolutely positive you had the charger connected correctly? If so, it might be a charger that puts a load on the battery to test it before charging, but unless the battery was fairly well discharged, that is an excessive drop.

**#2 - Do not do this.  Connecting multiple power supplies in parallel will probably result in damaging them.  It is okay to parallel supplies designed for that mode of operation, but even so, they must be matched in voltage output.
That being said, you just measure with a voltmeter to see what the total resultant voltage is, but I advise strongly that you do not attempt this.****